# How to set ConnectionString in ConfigMap and read the same from an ASP.NET Core App?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kubernetes, configmap

I have an ASP.NET Core WebApp which has to be deployed in Kubernetes using AKS via Azure DevOps Pipelines. For decoupling App Config from Source Code, I want to set the ConnectionString in Kubernetes ConfigMap and want to get the values from ConfigMap once it is deployed in Kubernetes. How to achieve this?